# How to find marginal demand?

Tags: finance

The demand for a product is given by $q=\frac{10}{\sqrt {4p+1}}$. find the marginal demand at p=6.

Worksheet i am solving contain all questions to find price elasticity of demand except above. And if i use formula of price elasticity then incorrect answer. Please help me.

Wow great. If anyone dont know even the formula. Then what to do?

Comment: How to you want to be helped if you don't explain what you already did ?

Comment: Is "price elasticity of demand" the same thing as "marginal demand"?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici i dont know which formula to use here. I used the formula of price elasticity of demand. But no correct result.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson i dont know. Thats why i asked this question here.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson any hint please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marginal demand: $\frac{dq}{dp}=\frac{-20}{(4p+1)^{3/2}}$.

Price elasticity of demand: $E_p=\frac{p}{q}\cdot \frac{dq}{dp}$.

Can you finish?

Comment: I get the same answer as you get. But the given $\frac4{25}$

Comment: What about the negative sign?

Comment: According to the law of demand, the price and quantity demanded are negatively related. That is, if price increases (decreases), the quantity demanded decreases (increases). Usually, the price elasticity of demand is also given as positive, although the relationship is negative. It goes without saying. Though cross-price elasticity is given as it is, because it shows the type of product (substitute or complementary).

Comment: Please answer me in simple words. Can we ignore negative sign? And Which answer is correct?

Comment: For the given demand function, I think, the sign must be negative.

Comment: @RajKumarSingh It depends how the price elasticity is defined you are supposed to use. in some cases it is defined with a negative sign and in other cases it is not.